# How to get all of database queries in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

How to get all of database queries in laravel 5.5? Something like log via `dd()`function

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging

Comment: yes, I saw it, but where exactly should I use it? Middleware/route files/controllers?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to debug your application actively (rather than just logging queries in the background or dumping them out onto the screen which will stop your app from executing) then using Debugbar is probably going to be the most user friendly option:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

You will end up with something that gives you an output like this for each page of your application (just ensure your .env file has debug set to true after you've installed it).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable query logging near the beginning of the request with `DB::enableQueryLog();`. Then after the request you have to log the requests using `DB::getQueryLog()`.

A middleware is a decent place to do this. I [wrote an example](https://gist.github.com/jfadich/21d7ced4c510bd140edf) a while back that may be of some use. It enables the DB query log then logs all the queries after the request has been processed. Copy the contents of that gist to `app/Http/Middleware/LogDatabaseQueries.php` then register it in your `Kernel.php`.

```
protected $middleware = [
    [...]
    \App\Http\Middleware\LogDatabaseQueries::class,
];
```